# Django: Authorization using query parameters

Tags: python, django, microservices

I'm writing a chat app where registered users can send messages to each other.

One of the components of this is a Django-based Messaging microservice, which has an API for sending and receiving messages.  For simplicity, there are only two URLs:

```
# List all messages in Thread "thread_id"
GET /threads/<int:thread_id>/messages/?user_id=123

# Send a message as user "user_id" to Thread "thread_id"
POST /threads/<int:thread_id>/messages/?user_id=123
```

This service is only visible internally, so there's no potential for spoofing `user_id`s.

Authorization is based on `user_id`, which is passed to the service as a query param and processed like so:

`views.py`:

```
class MessagesViewClass(django.views.View):

    def get(request, thread_id):

        # If this user is not part of this thread
        user_id = request.GET.get('user_id')
        if this_user_not_part_of_this_thread(user_id, thread_id):
            raise Some403Exception()

        else:
            process_response_normally()
```

Right now, I'm validating via a query parameter.  Is there a more conventional or canonical way of handling authorization of this type?

Answer (score 4):

Since only logged in user is allowed to view and receive messages, there is no need to send the user_id in the query parameters. You can use `request.user.id` to get the user id of the logged in user.